# Diff between 2 gsheets sheets rows with multiple columns

Tags: gsheets

I Have 2 sheets in a google sheet that have the same columns:

Name, Subject, Score

I want to create a new sheet where it lists all the rows in the second sheet that are not in the first sheet. Any change in one of the 3 columns should be in the new sheet.

Example

Sheet1

```
AAA, Math, 85
BBB, English, 50
BBB, History, 60
```

Sheet2

```
AAA, Math, 85
AAA, History, 50
BBB, English, 100
BBB, History, 60
CCC, Math, 100
```

ResultSheet

```
AAA, History, 50
BBB, English, 100
CCC, Math, 100
```

Is there a way to do this?